# Common techniques of cleaning memory in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to debug some code that another developer wrote in jquery since page loads really slow and crashes the browser. 
I need an advice how to test , debug big amounts of jquery code. 
Need some good techniques in memory cleanup in point of view of existing code written by somebody else. 
All the suggestions , tools , relevant links will be greatly appreciated.
I'm using firebug to debug the code.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: did you try any of the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QUnit
http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit

Answer (score 2):

go through this onload function , whatever code inside the below method gets executed onthe load of the page.Go through the code and identity all for loops , global variables , string concatination , null checks , div exists checks...

With the above things you can fix some...issues

run profiling in firebug also ,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // check for all null checks properly
// check global variables
// check forloops
// check circular references
     });
```

Comment: you can check firebug .net panel and see which http request is taking more time. You can sort by Memory , time in that. There are various things to check not only jquery. What technology you are using for serverside, any database calls , are you using implementing browser caching..There are lot of things to verify